# How can I count the highest level in a tree with recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, parent-child

So there's the mission.
We have a class, call NODE, the instance is "node".
This node has a lot of children, and these children have a lot of children too, etc etc.
How could I count the highest level in this tree?
etc:

- node -> child1 -> child1.1 -> child1.1.1, child 1.1.2 -> child1.1.2.1
- node -> child2
- node -> child3 -> child3.1, child3.2 -> child3.2.1

the highest level in this tree, is 4 (child1.1.2.1's level, node's level is 0)
Please help me!
I know, I should use recursive methods, but I don't know how, if anyone could solve this problem, and write a code... please...
Thank You!
The method should start with:

```
public int maxLevel(NODE node){...
```

Comment: So each `Node` holds an array of other `Node`s?

Comment: Can you show the code for your NODE class?  It would also probably be better to name it "Node" - all-caps is odd for class names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method returns a level of 1 for the base case (having 0 children):

```
public int maxLevel() {
    int maxChildLevel = 0;
    for (Node child : children) {
        maxChildLevel = Math.max(maxChildLevel, child.maxLevel());
    }
    return maxChildLevel + 1;
}
```

This example is meant to declare `maxLevel` as an instance method of `Node`, so there's no need for it to take a `Node` as an argument.

Comment: and would it be good too? "public int maxLevel(Node node)" and the for is "for(Node child: node.children){ maxChildLevel = Math.max(maxChildLevel, maxLevel(child));..."

Comment: @victorio That works too, but it seems like the method would be `static` if it takes a `Node` rather than being an instance method called on a `Node`.

Comment: and how could you SUM the levels? could you write a simple code?

Comment: @victorio That's a different question, but you should be able to figure it out yourself by applying what you've learned about recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public static int maxLevel(Node node) {
    if (node.children.length == 0) return 1;

    int max = maxLevel(node.children[0]);
    for (int i = 1 ; i < node.children.length ; i++) {
        int n = maxLevel(node.children[i]);
        if (n > max) max = n;
    }

    return max + 1;
}
```

where `node.children` is the array consisting of the child-nodes of `node`.

Comment: thank you! and how could you SUM the levels? could you write a simple code?